# Regex isolating a page path with only one set of "/" (backslashes)

Tags: regex, google-analytics

Meaning getting only page paths like with one path lvl like "/en/boy" and not "/en/boy/tshirt" or "/en/boy/".
The reason is that ist the only way for me to isolate product detail pages from the path.

I am trying to isolate url paths in Google Analytics

Comment: What language you are using? what have you done so far? be more specific when asking questions at SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
^(?:[^\/]*\/){2}[^\/]*$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/mdkdBb/2

Comment: Thank you. I solved it also by realising that I could just use the "not match regex" and use \/.*\/.*\/". But without this option yours is also working perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the language/platform, it might be slightly different, but if you're using grep:

```
grep -E '.*/en/boy$'
```

This will ensure you only get lines that have anything from beginning-of-line until `/en/boy`, with the `$` sign indicating that the line has to end there.